# Determine column data type from actual data values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to run sql stored procedure to evaluate the data type of a column based on the data. say I have loaded a text file and all columns are of char/varchar type, I would like to detect Numeric, date and string data types as basic
Have anyone wrote some code covering this in SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) and [ISDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) you can test the data to see if it is a numeric or date datatype.

Comment: Thank you, that will do the work! any chance there is a command similar to PROCEDURE ANALYZE in MySQL to give some more analysis on values?

Comment: http://www.ash.burton.fm/blogs/2010/12/quick-tip-mysql-equivalent-of-isnumeric     AND    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709744/isdate-equivalent-for-mysql