# Parsing Dates from strings without format specifiers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to parse dates from paragraphs in mysql stored procedure. which would looks like

```
  "1 may, 1776 some text some text 5 june 1776, some text some text 06 august 2027 
some text some text 20060803 some text some text 06 august 2028 some text some 
text 02-03-2019 some text some text 02/03/2014 some text some text 01/02/2012 
some text some text 03/08/06 some text some text 03/08/2006 some text some text 
3/8/06 some text some text 3/8/2006 some text some text 030806 some text some 
text 03082006 some text some text 03Aug06 some text some text 03Aug2006 some 
text some text 03-Aug-06 some text some text 03-Aug-2006 some text some text 
3Aug06 some text some text xvgdfg 3Aug2006"
```

where dates can be in many forms. 

So, I get to know mysql [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function which takes the string to need to be converted to date and a mysql date specifier format. but the I don't know the exact format to which I could try to parse date string & I couldn't find other good option to do this in mysql stored procedure. 
So, I'm just trying to know is there a way in mysql that could parse dates from string like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) in javascript or [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) in php or I need a lead to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you format your question,please? It's can not be read now

Comment: @lucumt I tried to format it. thank you for asking. Please let me know if  there anything I could do more to make this question more readable ?

Comment: This seems close to impossible in MySQL. It doesn't have any functions for parsing strings. If you're using MySQL 8.0 it has some new regexp functions, but your patterns are so general that it would be hard to write a regexp to match them all. And to process multiple matches in the string you'd have to write a stored procedure that loops.

Comment: Agree with @Barmar. There is too much variability in the date formats here. I ruled out using this simple approach to test your strings to see if they are a date...

SELECT DAYNAME(my_potential_date);

Works for this recognized format...
SELECT DAYNAME('20060803');

But does not work for an unrecognized date format...
SELECT DAYNAME('1 may, 1776');

Comment: Thanks Mr. Barmar & @JonJaussi, I know it'd be pretty much difficult to do things precisely. however I like Jon Jaussi's idea, will give that a try too. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. You may find this post useful as it goes into the example I provided in much more detail: [ISDATE() equivalent for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709744/isdate-equivalent-for-mysql)

Comment: @JonJaussi just to say, what i'm trying right now is [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qT1jsNzKGa8L1YqcU8etgZ/1)