# MySQL 8.0 STR_TO_DATE behaves differently when wrapped into user defined function

Tags: mysql, date, user-defined-functions

I am preparing a dataload from a temporary table containing pretty many columns. I decided to wrap some calls to system functions into UDF functions to be able to trim some behaviors in one shot and avoid nasty copy-pasting.

Now I got stuck on a strange behavior of STR_TO_DATE function.

Step by step:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(NULL,'%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('','%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('111','%m/%d/%Y') ;
```

This returns triple NULL value which is what I'd expect.

After that I have created the following UDF:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnProcessDateEntry; 
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION fnProcessDateEntry( str VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  RETURN STR_TO_DATE(str,'%m/%d/%Y') ; 
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

When running it against a properly formatted date it returns the expected result.
`SELECT fnProcessDateEntry('05/08/2023');` indeed returns 8th May, 2023. On top of that `SELECT fnProcessDateEntry(NULL);` returns NULL.

And now the thought part: if I run any of:

```
SELECT fnProcessDateEntry('');
SELECT fnProcessDateEntry('123');
```

I get no result set. In consequence, If I use `fnProcessDateEntry` in my huge dataload select - I also get no result set.

The workaround that comes to my mind is to use regexp to check if the string is a proper format within my UDF before applying `STR_TO_DATE`.

Anyway I'd love to understand the issue and control it in a more elegant manner.

Comment: Is it possible that you're getting a warning or error rather than just an empty result-set? Do you see something if you run `SHOW WARNINGS` and/or `SHOW ERRORS` afterwards?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yeah, indeed... I can see 1411 - Incorrect datetime value... Interesting: when called directly it is reported as Warning, if wrapped into UDF it is reported as Error Still not sure what is the best way to handle my stuff. Anyway I am much closer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked well enough:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnProcessDateEntry; 
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION fnProcessDateEntry( str VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
  BEGIN
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
    RETURN STR_TO_DATE(str,'%m/%d/%Y');
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

I am not fully happy with that solution.

- I'd prefer to check the param before passing it to `STR_TO_DATE` - but no clue how to achieve that (I've tried to imagine the proper regexp and got instant headache).
- I also suspect that playing with sql_mode could make `STR_TO_DATE` generate warning also when wrapped into UDF. But I want my UDF to be portable without caring about local settings, so did not investigate.

Credits to [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/) for pushing me in the correct direction.