# SQL Server SSIS : ADO.net date issue

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have created an SSIS package that pulls the data from Oracle 10g server and pushes them in SQL Server 2008.  I have date datatype field in Oracle named `admission_date`.

Below is my query in Oracle.

```
select pt_id,admission_date 
from stays
```

It works fine.

When I tried to pull the data in SQL Server through ADO.net via an SSIS package. I get the below error messages.

> Error: 0xC02090F5 at STAYS, ADO NET Source [1050]: The component "ADO
>   NET Source" (1050) was unable to process the data. ORA-01843: not a
>   valid month
>
> Error: 0xC0047038 at STAYS, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "ADO NET
>   Source" (1050) returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned
>   a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The
>   meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error
>   is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Any input on this would helpful.

Comment: Can you post some sample data from your `stays` table?

Comment: Please post the table layouts for the tables in Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: Stays Table structure :    pt_id|admission_date, Sample Data (123456|01-MAR-99,123457|01-MAR-99) that is my table structure in Oracle

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this TO_CHAR(addmission_date,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') to format your oracle date into a format that SQL likes.

Also be aware that Oracle has a much larger valid date range than SQL so depending upon your Oracle data you may have valid oracle dates that don't come across as valid SQL dates.

See [Dealing With Timestamp/Datetime when copying from Oracle to Sql Server using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2231164/236348)

And [Oracle to SQL2005 DATETIME field overflows in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229159/236348)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue was the Oracle table was a view and not a table , the admission_date was extracted from the decode command for SQL. I pulled as it is and it is resolved my issue.